# Build command from file content in makefile task

Tags: bash, replace, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to load the content of a file to **avoid showing sensitive data like passwords while invoking a command with `-p` during a makefile task execution**.

The command works when run without variable replacement. I am trying to run a `docker login` to a docker registry, but in theory this should not be relevant, I mean: the approach below could be used with any command not just the `docker` command.

I think I am messing up with the combination of double-quotes **"** and back-quotes **`** or something like that, but I can not find a way to get this working.

So far no luck with this `makefile` content as a combination of bash/gnu-make:

```
REGISTRY_PSW_FILE=./volume/conf/docker-registry.conf
REGISTRY_PSW=`cat $(REGISTRY_PSW_FILE)`
REGISTRY_LOGIN_COMMAND=docker login my-own-registry.something.com -u myRegistryUsr -p $(REGISTRY_PSW)

docker-push:
    @echo -e "\n\n\nPushing the docker image to the registry"
    @echo -e "stuff: $(REGISTRY_PSW)"
    @echo -e "more stuff: $(REGISTRY_LOGIN_COMMAND)"
    $(REGISTRY_LOGIN_COMMAND)
    @echo "DONE"
```

I've tried different things also stuff like:

```
REGISTRY_LOGIN_COMMAND=`docker login my-own-registry.something.com -u myRegistryUsr -p $(REGISTRY_PSW)`
```

Or this one using directly the `cat` command:

```
REGISTRY_LOGIN_COMMAND=docker login my-own-registry.something.com -u myRegistryUsr -p `cat $(REGISTRY_PSW_FILE)`
```

But I keep getting different errors like:

- `flag needs an argument: 'p' in -p \n See 'docker login --help'.`
- `Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://my-own-registry.something.com/v2 failed with status: 401 Unauthorized`

In the `makefile` task I am using `$(REGISTRY_LOGIN_COMMAND)` straight away (and not a combination of `eval` + `echo`) because I am trying to avoid showing the password in the output of the command (like in the `echo` that shows `more stuff: <THE THING I AM TRYING TO HIDE>`), anyway even when using a combination of `echo` and `eval` like this `@eval "echo -e $(REGISTRY_LOGIN_COMMAND)"` it still does not work with similar output errors.

I am using **cygwin** with the following version of gnu-make:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no way to prevent the user from seeing the docker command (and the password it contains), if Make runs the docker directly.

But if Make constructs a script that contains the docker command, and executes it, that's another story:

```
DOCKER_SCRIPT = run_docker

docker-push:
    sed -e 's/^/docker login my-own-registry.something.com -u myRegistryUsr -p /' -e 's|$$| >/dev/null/|' $(REGISTRY_PSW_FILE) > $(DOCKER_SCRIPT)
    chmod +x $(DOCKER_SCRIPT)
    ./$(DOCKER_SCRIPT)
```

Comment: Thanks :) I am seeing an error saying `./run_docker: line 1: /dev/null/: Not a directory`, but I think is just some Windows/cygwin/bash madness that I decided to workaround just putting the whole `docker login` command into a bash script and calling it from within the `Makefile` task like `./volume/conf/docker-registry.sh`. When the login is successful that's not showing any password in the output so for now it's fine. In the same `Makefile` task I am also tagging an image, then pushing it successfully so all good for now. I can tweak a bit the login script separating the password but it's ok.